# pandas how to override attibute error from timezome localization

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pytz

I have a **idaydf.index** that I am trying to localize timezone

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-10-24 16:00:00', '2022-10-24 16:15:00',
               ...
               '2023-06-16 21:58:00', '2023-06-16 22:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DateTime', length=9012, freq=None)
```

with

```
idaydf.index = idaydf.index.tz_localize(LOCAL_TZ)
```

where LOCAL_TZ is

```
_PytzShimTimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/London'), 'Europe/London')
```

I get this error:

```
*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

I have these versions:

```
python3-3.11.3
pandas-1.5.3
pytz-2023.3-1
tzlocal 4.2
```

How to fix?

Comment: I think you could use `.tz_localize(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(str(LOCAL_TZ)))` or update tzlocal to >= 5.0 so it returns a zoneinfo object instead of a pytz shim.

Comment: @Stef newest tzlocal version comes with another issue, see https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal/issues/147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the string representation of the timezone object to decouple. That way,

- pandas can chose whatever library it wants to handle the timezone (they're supposed to switch from pytz to zoneinfo still in 2023)
- the library that generates `LOCAL_TZ` can switch to zoneinfo without crashing your code
- you can avoid `try/except`s

Ex:

```py
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
import pytz_deprecation_shim as pds
import pandas as pd

LOCAL_TZ = pds.timezone('Europe/London')
print(repr(LOCAL_TZ))
# _PytzShimTimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/London'), 'Europe/London')

LOCAL_TZ_new = ZoneInfo('Europe/London')
print(repr(LOCAL_TZ_new))
# zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/London')

dti = pd.date_range('2022-10-24 16:00:00', '2023-06-16 22:00:00')

dti0 = dti.tz_localize(str(LOCAL_TZ))
dti1 = dti.tz_localize(str(LOCAL_TZ_new))

assert (dti0 == dti1).all()
```

---

Btw. `tzlocal` offers a way to directly obtain the IANA tz name as a string, which might make things even easier here -

```py
from tzlocal import get_localzone_name
get_localzone_name()
# "Europe/Berlin" # on my machine...
```

This works already with tzlocal version 4.2